# While continuously running Timer based event programming there was a jump in the events than expected. Why does it happen?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer, task, task-parallel-library

I will invoke a method called 'start' with Time Interval as '1 second'.
I wish to continue invoking certain actions in every 1 second interval. But while running it works by performing those actions according to Time Interval given. But when I observed the logs closely I could see intermittently it pauses for some time and then again starts.

Is there any problem with the async programming here?

**Example logs**

- Starting to send periodic Telemetry at 09:15:31.753
- Starting to send periodic Telemetry at 09:15:32.753
- Starting to send periodic Telemetry at **09:15:36**.753

  - See it skipped 4 seconds here

PublisherClass

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Test.Helpers
{
    public static class PublisherClass{
        public static List < System.Timers.Timer > SendPeriodicTimerObjs {
            get;
            set;
        } = new List < System.Timers.Timer > ();

        public static async Task PublishToMethod(string methodName, string message) {
            try {
                string topic;               
                switch (methodName) {
                case "start":
                    var sendPeriodicObj = new SendPeriodicTelemetry();
                    sendPeriodicObj.periodicTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                    SendPeriodicTimerObjs.Add(sendPeriodicObj.periodicTimer);
                    if (methodName == "start") {
                        var timeIntervel = 1000;
                        sendPeriodicObj.periodicTimer.Interval = timeIntervel;
                        sendPeriodicObj.SetTimer(timeIntervel, sendPeriodicObj.periodicTimer);
                        await CommonMethods.AckMethod(CommonMethods.listMessage, CommonMethods.requestId, MethodNames.start);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SendPeriodicTelemetry

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace Test.Helpers
{
    public class SendPeriodicTelemetry
    {    
         public void SetTimer(Timer timer)
        {
            timer.Elapsed += SendPeriodic;
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        public async void SendPeriodic(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {         
            Console.WriteLine("Starting to send periodic Telemetry at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}", e.SignalTime);
            await SendPeriodicTimeSeries(TimeSeriesTopic, TelemetrySingle, Configuration);
            await SendPeriodicAlarm(AlarmTopic, AlarmSingle);
            await SendPeriodicEvent(EventTopic, EventSingle);
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S:** See the code works fine continuously invoking the three actions on 1 second interval. It never stops. But problem is as stated it intermittently pauses for certain seconds and again re-starts. I have no idea why it happens.

Comment: Could you try adding `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);` at the start of the program, to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: `System.Timers.Timer` under the hood uses `System.Threading.Timer` which posts events to the thread pool.  If the thread pool is full, then the execution of the next event can be delayed.

Is there a chance that any of the code in `SendPeriodic` blocks a thread for a few seconds?

Comment: @Nick All the three methods 'SendPeriodicTimeSeries', 'SendPeriodicAlarm' and 'SendPeriodicEvent' did some specific calculations and finally calls the one asynchronous common method called 'Publish()' from another class. I don't think so that makes any difference.

Comment: @KBNanda, it _can_ make a difference.  If any of these calculations, or `Publish()` can take a few secs sometimes, esp. if they have to block / wait on something.  If the thread pool gets exhausted, you will have delays.  Mind you, you can exhaust your thread pool by other async activities you do.

Answer (score -1):

> "... although we enabled our timer to trigger every one second, the event handler was delayed in order to handle other activity of
> the CPU. Server-based timers are dependent on the operating system's
> multithreading character on which our code runs, and the program must
> obey the CPU priority rules when using these timers." - [c-sharpcorner.com](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/timers-in-C-Sharp/)

You want to search for "high resolution timer" or "accurate metronome timer".

You might end up in a position where you have to decide what is more important: the computers other demanding computations, or pin-point accurate telemetry. You can live with delayed telemetry, optimise those other computations, increase hardware requirements, or some combination of these things.